# How can I apply custom syntax highlighting in VIM to all file types?

Tags: vim

The most preferable way to do this would be in some like my `.vimrc` file or another location in my `vimfiles` that's easily persisted and not attached to an extra plugin.

The help files for VIM (along with almost all solutions found on the Internet abroad) relate directly to adding syntax highlighting for a specific file type.

However, how would one add highlights that apply to *all* files?

An example would be highlighting extra keywords as part of the `Todo` highlighting group - such as "NOTE", "INTERNAL", etc.

I've attempted to use `vimfiles\after\syntax\...`, but again, it seems to be predicated on the right file type getting used for the `.vim` file created in that directory.

So, something like `vimfiles\after\syntax\cpp.vim` with the following works to achieve this in C++:

```
syntax keyword cTodo contained NOTE INTERNAL IMPORTANT
```

for C++ files specifically, and this works how I would expect it to.

But how can this be generalized to *all* file types when a file is loaded into a buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook into the syntax script loading via the `Syntax` event. Be sure to define this *after* `:syntax on` in your .vimrc:

```
:autocmd Syntax * syntax keyword allTodo NOTE
```

If you also want to handle buffers that don't have any syntax (/ filetype) set, add the `BufNewFile,BufReadPost` events.

#### Alternative

Depending on the syntax, you may need to specify `contained[in]`, or `:syn cluster add=...` to augment the existing syntax. That unfortunately cannot be generalized. An alternative approach would be using `:match` or `:call matchadd(...)`, which goes on top of (and is totally independent of) syntax highlighting. Since this is window-local, the autocmd would be:

```
:autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter * match Todo /\<NOTE\>/
```

Comment: looks like I had to go the alternative route. C / C++ source files look to require "contained" which ends up not working with the `syntax` route. Although I pretty much achieved what I needed with matching. Though I did have to use `matchadd()` instead to get some separate highlights on a few different keywords.